# C# not connecting to DB2 via MS Provider DB2OLEDB

Tags: c#, db2, oledb

I am pretty new to DB2 (since today...) and I need to connect to a DB2 instance I run locally on my computer.

I installed the DB2 community edition and the Microsoft DB2OLEDB Provider.

When I open the DB2 dialogue, I can connect to my local instance (port 50000) and if I open the DB2 command plus window, the connection succeeds as well.

Now, I created a small C# Console app, which uses the OleDBConnection to open a connection to this local instance.

I tried several connection strings:

```
Provider=DB2OLEDB;Database=Sample;Hostname=localhost;Protocol=TCPIP;Port=50000;Uid=....;Pwd=....;

Provider=DB2OLEDB;Network Transport Library=TCPIP;Host=127.0.0.1:50000;Initial Catalog=Sample;User ID=....;Password=....
```

No matter what I try, I always receive the error:

```
A TCPIP socket error has occurred (10061): connection could not be established because teh remote computer rejected the connection (<-- translated from german... don't know the exact english error message)
```

Now, if port 50000 wasn't open, the connection via DB2 and DB2 command plus shouldn't be possible as well, should it? As mentioned server as well as the C# program are running on my local computer.

Any hints what I am missing here?

Comment: See following : https://www.connectionstrings.com/ibm-db2/

Comment: IS the db2sysc process for your instance really listening on port 50,000 ?  Verify this at the command-line prompt with the command `netstat -a -b`. If port 50000 is not shown as LISTENING by process db2sysc, then run command `db2cwadmin` and in the resulting window run `db2set -g DB2COMM=TCPIP` (and any other protocol you need), followed by `db2stop force` and `db2start`. Then retry the connection.

Comment: If you can use an ADO.NET provider that directly works with DB2 instead of using OLEDB as a go-between, that would be optimal, and jdweng's link would apply to that.  Check out [IBM.Data.DB2.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBM.Data.DB2.Core/) and use `DB2Connection`.

Comment: @mao db2syscs.exe is listening to Port 50000 for TCP...

Comment: @jdweng thx, already found this link, but we are currently using MS DB2OLEDB and not IBMs OLEDB...

Comment: @madreflection yeah, nice idea. But the plan is to integrate this into an existing application, which is using OLE DB to connect to SQL Server, MS Analysis Services, Oracle SQL... they all are called via the OLE DB library... thought it would be rather nice to have one type of connection for all systems...

Comment: I just managed to get a connection using the IMB OLEDB Provider... but anyways: why the heck is the MS DB2OLEDB Provider not working / rejected? They use the same server and port... would like to understand what went wrong.